# IsolatedStorage createFile not working

Tags: silverlight

I am getting FileNotFoundException when I make the following call:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile("abc.txt");
```

However, if I have a textbox on my page and do:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile(textBox1.Text)
```

then this works.
I am using Silverlight 3.

Any ideas why I get the error?

JD

Comment: Have you double-checked this? It seems very unlikely.

Comment: Hi Henrik, yes, double and triple checked it. I have a working app with a textbox. Even if I create a variable that stores textbox1.text, I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the FileNotFoundException internal to the CreateFile call?  Check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bc1f2a11-32e1-4752-afcd-ba6f295cab1a).

Comment: Thanks Will. I turned off exceptions and I still get the error. Only when using the textBox do I not get the error. Yes the exception is internal to CreateFile.

Comment: Sorry Will, it looks like it is the exceptions (turning on and off) that was causing it. Thanks.

Comment: np - glad to be of assistance.